# What field is used to pass on transaction information? input field or data field?

Tags: transactions, data

In the documentation [here](https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation/) under the `eth_sendTransaction`, it shows/states that in the transaction object sent, there is an input field.

But in the documentation [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_sendtransaction) it says there is a data field.

My question is, which is correct? When crafting a transaction object, under what field should information about arguments and which methods on the smart contracts to be invoked included in? data field? or input field?

Answer (score 0):

`data`, `input` and `topics` can be used to display methods and their argument datas used in each transaction.

In regards to

> methods on the smart contract to be invoked

..it isn’t necessary to contain this information in the various fields within a transaction object. This can be plainly viewed in the contract ABI.

Comment: this does not answer the question though

Comment: “ When crafting a transaction object, under what field should information about arguments and which methods on the smart contracts to be invoked included in? data field? or input field?”
- in direct answer to your question: neither data or input field are used to display “methods on the smart contract to be invoked”

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling `eth_sendTransaction` it looks like geths rpc can accept either, I personally have only done it under `data` though

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c2db667c8f824ec0d025cbde95e6aaad67fc10ba/internal/ethapi/transaction_args.go#L37